# How can I cut and replaced on illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector

[image]

this is not the actual picture but lets say that girl was vectorized in illustrator. I want to know how can I cut 1 piece of puzzle in vectorized picture and place it somewhere using illustrator, as I did this sample photo on photoshop.
I knew its possible, its just thing that I am bit beginner on Illustrator.

note to admin/mod: please correct my english if there's an error, thanks.

Comment: Why should we ruin such a beautiful girl!?

Comment: Even how matter I ruin the whole puzzle, she is still beautiful.

her name is Vika Levina, A russian model

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Javascript to do this; see https://forums.adobe.com/thread/735457 for a description (direct download link: http://www.jongware.com/binaries/puzzlify.zip).

[image: example usage]

After running the script, you end up with separate puzzle pieces, which you can move around at will.

The script assumes a single object or group is selected before running. It asks for a few simple parameters, such as how many rows and columns should be created. It does not work in the faux perspective of your example, it assumes a plain orientation. If you want the effect you show, first transform the entire image in a proper "upright" position, then run my script, select all puzzle pieces, and transform them back to the slanted orientation.

Note that it creates a *full copy* of all of the objects for each separate piece. If your image is object-heavy (an autotraced image usually is), consider rasterizing it before running the script.

Comment: I created it in perspective way, and I really need it as a vector format. is there possible way?.
by the way thanks for the script.